# variable number of leading zeros

Tags: python

In Python we can do

```
"file_{:03}.ext".format(i)
```

allowing us to easily pad any number `i` with leading zeros to fit any given width.

But what if the desired width is only known at runtime?  Can we still achieve the same effect?

Comment: Construct the filter string dynamically, and fill in whatever value you want instead of `03`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out after I asked it :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, string formatting supports nesting.

```
>>> "file_{:0{}}.ext".format(42, 3)
'file_042.ext'
>>> "file_{:0{}}.ext".format(42, 5)
'file_00042.ext'
```

Comment: Oh cool, I tried several things but wasn't able to get the nesting working.  Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn’t specify the python version I’ll state this is also easily done with f-strings as well! (py3.6+)

```
>>> value = 42
>>> width = 3
>>> f"file_{value:0{width}}.ext"
'file_042.ext'
>>> width = 5
>>> f"file_{value:0{width}}.ext"
'file_00042.ext'
```

Comment: Now that's some sorcery!

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

Given a desired integer width `d`, first create a format string via string concatenation, then call format.

```
d = 3
format_string = "file_{:0" +str(d) + "}.ext"
format_string.format(d)
```

yields

```
'file_003.ext'
```